# Exclude folder matching string within for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Given a for loop such as this:

```
FOR /d /r "topDir" %%G in (*foo*) DO (
    echo %%G
)
```

is there a way to exclude certain folders?
Specifically do not echo anything if the folder's name is **foobar**.
But *do* echo if it contains foo and is anything but **foobar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `for /f` loop to process a more complex command:

```
set "topDir=c:\topDir"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (' dir /s /a:d "%topDir%\*foo*"^| find /v "foobar"') do (
   echo %%a
)
```

another option:

```
FOR /d /r "topDir" %%G in (*foo*) DO (
    echo %%G | find /v "foobar" 1>nul 2>nul && (
        echo %%G
    ) 
)
```

Comment: the first one gives me `delims" was unexpected at this time.`?

Comment: `delims` option equals a value. Instead of `delims"`, try `delims="`. I suspect it is a typo.

Comment: I'd suggest using `findstr /v /i /x "foobar"` not `findstr /v "foobar"` as the latter will also find `notfoobar` and `foobar1` and exclude them. oh, and for  the first, `dir /s /b /a:d` for basic output.

Comment: @zhzoo - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell can be used to select directories and exclude specific names.

```
C:>TYPE t.bat
@echo off
DIR /A:D
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%d IN (`powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Filter '*foo*' -Exclude 'foobar' | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }"`) DO (
    ECHO Selected directory is %%d
)
```

And an example execution.

```
C:>CALL t.bat
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0E33-300C

 Directory of C:\src\t\f

2017-12-31  16:46    <DIR>          .
2017-12-31  16:46    <DIR>          ..
2017-12-31  16:12    <DIR>          barfoo
2017-12-31  16:12    <DIR>          barfoochow
2017-12-31  16:12    <DIR>          foo
2017-12-31  16:12    <DIR>          foobar
2017-12-31  16:39    <DIR>          zzz
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  792,276,733,952 bytes free
Selected directory is barfoo
Selected directory is barfoochow
Selected directory is foo
```